# SameSite cookie policy setting when supporting both old Safari and new Chrome in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, cookies, samesite

I have a Laravel 7 application with a Cordova based webview app as a secondary interface.
To support cross domain requests from the app, I can't use SameSite policies strict or lax.

Apparently Chrome has changed (and temporarily rolled back) the cookie samesite default value to lax.
Which means I should set the SameSite policy to none.

But if I set my SameSite policy to none, then older Safari webviews think none means strict. And my app won't work on those devices. Which means I shouln't set SameSite at all? (Laravel setting null)

What should i do, so I can serve both old Safari and new Chrome browsers?
Can Laravel change the SameSite setting dynamically depending on the user agent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can detect the UserAgent for the browser, and then don't serve the SameSite setting to the browsers that don't support it.

The Chromium blog has a great article about it https://www.chromium.org/updates/same-site/incompatible-clients

That should cover everything for you!